# Traefik self signed certificate on openshift with the ingress object

Tags: ssl, openshift, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a problem where i can create an ingress object, and make it work with https but it does not provide a custom certificate I have created and specified in the "ingress" object.

I am using openshift as the orchestrator.
I am using "ingress" as a provider and the "ingress" object for traefik.

How can I create and enable a self-signed certificate that traefik will use?
In addition, how can I change the default certificate traefik gives me?

My configurations:

I have installed traefik via the default values.yaml file and via the helm chart here:
https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/tree/master

My ingress object:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-http
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - traefik.ben-tests.com
     secretName: my-tls
  rules:
    - host: traefik.ben-tests.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /iamben
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: whoami-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

When i do:
`curl https://traefik.ben-tests.com/iamben  -k` or access via web i get the default traefik certificate.

I have created the certificate via the following commands:

To create the certificate:
`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout my.key -out my.crt`

To create the secret:
`oc create secret generic my-tls --from-file=tls.key=my.key --from-file=tls.crt=my.crt`

What am i doing wrong?
Ty very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i signed the certificate it had no SAN so the certificate was not valid, thus traefik served the default one.

Created a new valid crt via openssl (version 1.1.1)

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes   -keyout my.key -out my.crt -subj "/CN=traefik.ben-tests.com"   -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:*.traefik.ben-tests.com,DNS:traefik.ben-tests.com"`

And it worked :)